# Add dynamic content to annotations in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

Is it possible to add dynamic content like pipeline parameters to Azure Data Factory annotations, so that i can filter on them and group by them in the monitor?

Answer (score 6):

It is possible, but very limited.
You cannot add dynamic content to annotations in trigger or datasets. If you do, the elements will validate, but they will throw an error on execution.

But it is possible to add dynamic content in pipeline annotations. As annotations have been disappearing from the UI, you need to open the code of the pipeline (either by cloning the repo to your local machine and open the json file, or by clicking on the {} sign in the top right corner of your pipeline view). On the very bottom you will find

```
"annotations": []
```

Here you can add for example dynamic pipeline parameters like this:

```
"annotations": [
    "@pipeline().parameters.<parametername>"
]
```

For every run of the pipeline an annotation will be added with the parameter set for the current run.